# Как правильно употреблять «дело в том, что»?

Tags: словоупотребление

Скажите пожалуйста как правильно употреблять конструкцию «дело в том, что»? Какая разница между «потому, что», «так как» «поскольку» и «дело в том, что»?

Comment: Виктор, не используйте, пожалуйста, < и > в качестве кавычек.

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, знаки <> в качестве кавычек - это китайский синтаксис, почему бы не привнести немного экзотики?

Comment: Спасибо за напоминание. Подмены кавычек не будет в моих вопросах.

Answer (score 4):

**«потому что»**, **«так как»**, **«поскольку»** более или менее синонимичны, могут отличаться регистром, в частности «потому, что», будет пониже регистром, чем два других союза.

**«дело в том, что»** применяется не как союз сложноподчинённого предложения, который вводит обстоятельство причины, а как вводная фраза, предваряющая изложение причин или аргументов [в новом предложении](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE+%D0%B2+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC,+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%22)

Например:

> Я сегодня опоздал, потому что/так как/поскольку мой будильник не
>   зазвонил.
>
> Я сегодня опоздал. Дело в том, что мой будильник не зазвонил.

Во фразе **«дело в том, что»** слово **«дело»** по сути означает **«причина»**, то есть **«причина в том, что»**

> Я сегодня опоздал. Причина в том, что мой будильник не зазвонил.

Answer (score 1):

Следует различать также ", потому что" и "потому, что". §108 http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm

Наиболее разговорная форма из перечисленных автором вопроса - "потому что". "Так как", "поскольку", "ввиду того, что", "по той причине, что" - более официальны, могут использоваться в лекциях и публичных выступлениях, хотя и "потому что" тоже их не испортит.

Comment: Я много нового узнал, после того как прочитал ваш материал. Спасибо вам, Елена!

Answer (score 1):

Синонимичные выражения разной степени формальности *"потому(,) что", "так как" и "поскольку"* указывают на **простую** (часто единственную) **причину** *непосредственно* - когда связь с указываемой причиной понятна без развёрнутых пояснений. Если же предстоит объяснение скрытых причин, то после указания на сложность их понимания такое объяснение может предваряться *вступительной фразой*: "**Дело в том что...**". Примеры:

> Казалось бы, причина  явления в этом. Но не всё так просто: **дело в
>   том, что** на это накладываются обстоятельства, которые мы пока не
>   учитывали.
>
> Но в общем случае не существует простых формул для расчёта элементов
>   лестничного фильтра. **Дело в том, что**...